# Mostrar tabla con los datos al buscar cédula, al parecer no está ejecutando la sentencia del sql

Tags: php7, ms-access

¿Cómo mostrar la tabla con los datos al buscar cédula? Al parecer no está ejecutando la sentencia de SQL:

```
<?php
         
         // Datos de conexión
            $database = realpath("Casos.accdb");
            $dsn = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=$database;";
            $user = '';
            $password = '';
            
         // Establecer la conexión
            $connection = odbc_connect($dsn, $user, $password);
    
         // Verificar la conexión
            if (!$connection) {
                exit("Error al conectar con la base de datos");
            } else {
                echo "Conexión exitosa";
            }

         // Consulta SQL para buscar los datos del beneficiario según la Cédula ingresada
            if(isset($_POST['mostrar'])) {
            $Cédula = $_POST['personas'];
            
            $ssql = "SELECT Beneficiario, Fecha_Asistido, Edad, Municipio, Parroquia, Direccion, Medicamentos, Material_Quirurgico, Insumos_Medicos, Otras_Solicitudes  FROM Casos  WHERE Cedula_Representante = $Cédula OR Cedula_Beneficiario = $Cédula";
            
                
         // Ejecutar la consulta
            $result = odbc_exec($connection, $ssql);
            //if (!$result) { exit("Error al ejecutar la consulta"); }
            if (!$result) { exit("Error al ejecutar la consulta: " . odbc_errormsg($connection));
}
    
         // Verificar si se encontraron registros
            if (odbc_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                
         // Mostrar la tabla con los datos encontrados
            echo "<table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Beneficiario</th>
                    <th>Fecha_Asistido</th>
                    <th>Edad</th>
                    <th>Municipio</th>
                    <th>Parroquia</th>
                    <th>Direccion</th>
                    <th>Medicamentos</th>
                    <th>Material_Quirurgico</th>
                    <th>Insumos_Medicos</th>
                    <th>Otras_Solicitudes</th>
                </tr>";
        
            while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr>
                    <td>{$row['Beneficiario']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['Fecha_Asistido']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['Edad']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['Municipio']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['Parroquia']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['Direccion']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['Medicamentos']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['Material_Quirurgico']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['Insumos_Medicos']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['Otras_Solicitudes']}</td>
                </tr>";
        }
        
            echo "</table>";
    }       else {
         // Mostrar mensaje si no se encontraron registros
            echo "No existe la Cédula ingresada";
    }
    }
           odbc_close($connection);
```

Comment: Access sigue vivo? bueno, eso no importa, qué devuelve el programa? error? mensaje del propio programa? nada? por cierto, insertar sentencias sql directamente desde el usuario es una mala práctica que conlleva ataques sql injection.